# Invoking AWS Lambda via CLI returns ERROR: Could not parse payload into json: Unexpected character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 145)):

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to follow along the [AWS Getting Started with Lambda Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started.html), but I am having Issues actually invoking my Function using the CLI.

I came across [THIS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-awscli.html) step and got two errors:

> An error occurred (InvalidRequestContentException) when calling the
> Invoke operation: Could not parse request body into json: Could not
> parse payload into json: Unexpected character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 145)):
> expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token
> 'null', 'true' or 'false')  at [Source: (byte[])"��j[�"; line: 1,
> column: 2]

and

> An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the
> GetLogEvents operation: The specified log group does not exist.

I assume the first error is caused by the first command :
aws lambda invoke --function-name my-function --payload '{"key": "value"}' out.json

and the second error accordingly by:
aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name /aws/lambda/my-function --log-stream-name $(cat out) --limit 5

I am more concerned about the first error.
I tried to solve this, by looking at the documentation for invoking a lambda function using the CLI. The most basic example was:

> aws lambda invoke --function-name my-function --payload '{ "key":
> "value" }' response.json

Using this, I get the same Error code

> Could not
> parse payload into json: Unexpected character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 145)):

I have asked about this in the AWS Dev Forums, but have not gotten any answer.
There where a few topics about similar errors on Stackoverflow, however they mentioned a specific character that was missing in the payload to be valid JSON.
According to google "CTRL-CHAR" sometimes points out a line break in your JSON, but there are none in this example. As far, as I can tell, the payload is valid JSON.

According to the CLI Documentation, you can also use other data types as payload. So I tried just passing a list:

> aws lambda invoke --function-name my-func2 --payload '[2, 3, 4, 5]' out.json

I got the error:

> Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into
> json: Unrecognized token 'Û': was expecting (JSON String, Number,
> Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')

Comment: Have you tried to create a Lambda function using the AWS SDK? If so. what languages?

Comment: @smac2020 No, I have created a standard lambda function, using the AWS Management Console. Language is Python 3.8

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone ever gets stuck at the same point while doing the official Lambda Tutorial:

I had the issue solved by adding:
--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out
as a parameter.

According to : [CLI 2 AWS DOCS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration.html#cliv2-migration-binarypara)

This has something to do with encoding changes from CLI 1 to CLI 2.
It can also be added to to the aws config file, so you dont have to add it manually every time.

However, I am not sure why the Lambda Tutorial would not mention this, since the tutorial assumes you use CLI 2 and also guides you through the steps of the installation...

Answer (score 0):

For me this way it worked in windows:

`aws lambda invoke --function-name Func2 --payload {\"key1\":\"val1\"} --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out out.json`

As suggested by MrTony, I added **"--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out"** args

Answer (score 0):

## **Configurations**

- Mac OS
- VS code

## **Error**

`--payload`

> The JSON that you want to provide to your Lambda function as input.
>
> You can enter the JSON directly. For example, `--payload '{ "key": "value" }'` . You can also specify a file path. For example, `--payload file://payload.json` .

[source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html#options)

## **Correction**

you need to clarify with this command:

```
--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out
```

## **Method**

Here is the correct syntax:

```
aws lambda invoke \
> --invocation-type RequestResponse \
> --function-name my-function \
> --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
> --payload '{ "key": "value" }'  response.json
```

Run your code again